# VDPAU library not found

Tags: compiling, drivers, gentoo, video

I want to try this [VAAPI backend for VDPAU](https://github.com/i-rinat/libvdpau-va-gl). I have compiled **mplayer** with vdpau in Gentoo Linux (amd64) but I get this error:

```
Failed to open VDPAU backend libvdpau_nvidia.so: cannot open shared object file: No such file or directory
[vdpau] Error when calling vdp_device_create_x11: 1
```

The same error appears when I run **vdpauinfo**. The library seems to be linked:

```
$ ldd /usr/bin/mplayer | grep vdpau
    libvdpau.so.1 => /usr/lib64/libvdpau.so.1 (0x00007f8242fda000)
```

And libraries exist:

```
$ ls -l /usr/lib64/libvdpau.so*
lrwxrwxrwx 1 root root    17 jul  8 22:24 /usr/lib64/libvdpau.so -> libvdpau.so.1.0.0
lrwxrwxrwx 1 root root    17 jul  8 22:24 /usr/lib64/libvdpau.so.1 -> libvdpau.so.1.0.0
-rwxr-xr-x 1 root root 14560 jul  8 22:24 /usr/lib64/libvdpau.so.1.0.0 
$ ls -l /usr/lib64/vdpau/
total 156
lrwxrwxrwx 1 root root     23 jul  8 22:24 libvdpau_trace.so -> libvdpau_trace.so.1.0.0
lrwxrwxrwx 1 root root     23 jul  8 22:24 libvdpau_trace.so.1 -> libvdpau_trace.so.1.0.0
-rwxr-xr-x 1 root root  51032 jul  8 22:24 libvdpau_trace.so.1.0.0
lrwxrwxrwx 1 root root     19 jul 12 21:34 libvdpau_va_gl.so -> libvdpau_va_gl.so.1
-rwxr-xr-x 1 root root 105360 jul 12 21:34 libvdpau_va_gl.so.1
```

Comment: The reason the linkage is not obvious may be because it is `libvdpau.so` (not `mplayer`) which relies on `libvdpau_nvidia.so`.

Comment: This may be useful to others - I had this error on Debian 8 - it was preventing VLC image from displaying (though sound was still working). Rebooting fixed it.

Answer (score 1):

The issue is with `libvdpau_nvidia.so` missing. I found this Q&A on askubuntu titled: [GNOME Mplayer: “Failed to open VDPAU backend libvdpau_nvidia.so” error](https://askubuntu.com/questions/13487/gnome-mplayer-failed-to-open-vdpau-backend-libvdpau-nvidia-so-error). There were 2 fixes identified in this question.

1. link nvidia to libvdpau

   ```
   $ ln -s /usr/lib/vdpau/libvdpau_nvidia.so.1 /usr/lib/libvdpau_nvidia.so
   ```
2. use a different codec

   ```
   $ mplayer -vo xv video.wmv
   ```

Comment: Neither is useful. 1# I think is not valid because I have no `libvdpau_nvidia.so` in `/usr/lib/vdpau`, as you can see in my question. So do you need NVIDIA drivers to use the VDPAU API?. 2# has no sense, because xv driver has not hardware support for H.264 or MPEG video decoding.

Comment: @el_Salmon Yes, you need the NVIDIA drivers.

Comment: Actually, other manufacturers have started releasing VDPAU-compatible drivers (but of course you still need one). The generic libvdpau is only a wrapper around your driver's implementation. http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/VDPAU

Comment: It's not answering your original question, but I'm guessing that because you're trying to use a VDPAU driver with a VA-API backend, you may find [this](https://wiki.gentoo.org/wiki/VAAPI) useful (particularly the section about MPlayer). `libvdpau` is also hardcoded to load the NVidia driver according to [this](https://wiki.gentoo.org/wiki/VDPAU) link.